# run application from background from ane throw status notification

Tags: android, air

I am writing application on action sctipt for android using Adobe AIR 3.2 with native extentions. My task is to make notification throw native extentions, to make available to click on that notification and it must open application from background. I already made to run notification, but I can't run application when I clicking on it. How cant I do that? What I done wrong? Help me please, thanks.

```
package com.company.extensions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

  import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;

import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREFunction;

public class ToolsExtensionContext extends FREContext 
{
    public Vibrator vb = null;

    @Override
    public void dispose() 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, FREFunction> getFunctions() 
    {
        Map<String, FREFunction> functionMap = new HashMap<String, FREFunction>();

        functionMap.put("notifyUser", new ToolsNotifyFunction());

        return functionMap;
    }

    void notifyUser()
    {
        Log.d("bla-bla-bla", "Just bla");


        // look up the notification manager service
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // The details of our fake message
        CharSequence from = "Hello";
        CharSequence message = "Some message!";

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
        // notification.  Note the use of FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT so that, if there
        // is already an active matching pending intent, cancel it and replace
        // it with the new array of Intents.
        Intent k = new Intent(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ToolsExtensionContext.class);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                0, k , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // The ticker text, this uses a formatted string so our message could be localized
        String tickerText = "Tiker text";

        // construct the Notification object.
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.close, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100000);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), from, message, null);//contentIntent);

        // We'll have this notification do the default sound, vibration, and led.
        // Note that if you want any of these behaviors, you should always have
        // a preference for the user to turn them off.
        notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Note that we use R.layout.incoming_message_panel as the ID for
        // the notification.  It could be any integer you want, but we use
        // the convention of using a resource id for a string related to
        // the notification.  It will always be a unique number within your
        // application.
        nm.notify(1, notif);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code to send local notifications on Android, and after pressing on notification resume to the application at the same activity, when it was before going background:

```
void sendLocalNotification()
    {

        // look up the notification manager service
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // The details of our fake message
        CharSequence from = "Hello";
        CharSequence message = "some message";

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
        // notification.  Note the use of FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT so that, if there
        // is already an active matching pending intent, cancel it and replace
        // it with the new array of Intents.


        Intent k = new Intent(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), this.getActivity().getClass());
        Log.d("bla-bla-bla",  this.getActivity().getClass().toString());
        k.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        k.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);


        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                0, k , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
        //      0, k , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // The ticker text, this uses a formatted string so our message could be localized
        String tickerText = "Tiker text";

        // construct the Notification object.
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.close, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100000);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), from, message, contentIntent);

        // We'll have this notification do the default sound, vibration, and led.
        // Note that if you want any of these behaviors, you should always have
        // a preference for the user to turn them off.
        notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Note that we use R.layout.incoming_message_panel as the ID for
        // the notification.  It could be any integer you want, but we use
        // the convention of using a resource id for a string related to
        // the notification.  It will always be a unique number within your
        // application.
        nm.notify(1, notif);
    }
```